# How to set the volume of background music in cocos2d android

Tags: android, audio, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-android

I usually before implementing the task in original project used to test it on "dummy" one, likewise now tested "volume setting of background music" that is to increase and decrease volume of the music in cocos2d-android project, but this works for "dummy" project not on the original project, i compared the code but could not get why its not working:(
 here's the code.

```
public class SplashScene extends CCLayer {

public SplashScene() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    Global.createSprite(this, "splash_320x480.png", 160, 240);
    schedule("gameBegin", 5);
    Context context = CCDirector.sharedDirector().getActivity();
    SoundEngine.sharedEngine().preloadEffect(context, R.raw.pew_pew_lei);
    SoundEngine.sharedEngine().playSound(context, R.raw.rock, true);
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (hasFocus) {
        Global.m_SoundEngine.setSoundVolume(1.0f);
        Global.m_SoundEngine.setEffectsVolume(1.0f);
    } else {
        Global.m_SoundEngine.setSoundVolume(0.0f);
        Global.m_SoundEngine.setEffectsVolume(0.0f);
    }
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
}
```